# In Visual Studio 2012 (C#) How to Create Custom Macros available in Post Build

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I want to add in a Post-build event commandline in my Visual Studio 2012 C# project.

I have a number of projects in my solution and I would like to add to the list of macros available with "Macros>>".

How can I achieve this?

For instance I have the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f MYPFXFILEPATH /p MYPASSWORD /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
```

I would hate to copy and paste that into every project.  I would like to place the first part into a macro so that I would have:

```
$(SignCommandLinePrefix) $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
```

Answer (score 8):

Though you won't see your macro in the **Macros>>** list, you can edit your **.csproj** file by hand. Look for the first `<PropertyGroup>` and add this right before the closing `</PropertyGroup>`**:**

```
<SignCommandLinePrefix>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f MYPFXFILEPATH /p MYPASSWORD /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll</SignCommandLinePrefix>
```

Now, you can add `$(SignCommandLinePrefix) $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)` to your Post-Build Event and it will work just as you wish.

Check out Chuck England's response to this question:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/e774f871-8fc2-4875-b791-1df3dd0bb2dc/