# Add environment macro to C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to run a utility (mt.exe) as a post-build step in a C# project.  There is an environment variable/macro defined as DevEnvDir accessed by $(DevEnvDir).  However, mt.exe is an SDK tool and not in the Visual Studio executable tree.  Visual C++ projects have the WindowsSdkDir variable accessible by $(WindowsSdkDir).  Ideally, I would want to have in my C# post build project a line that starts something like:

$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\x86\mt.exe .....

Is there anyway to add the WindowsSdkDir environment variable/macro to my C# environment?

I realize I could hard code the path, but I want something I can share between machines and developers.

Comment: Just a guess: Right-click properties, and go to the Reference Paths tab.

Comment: The macros are specific to the project. C++ uses the SDK whereas C# does not. So, if you want to add your own macros, you'll have to edit the project and add them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632282/in-visual-studio-2012-c-how-to-create-custom-macros-available-in-post-build